# How to fix this error - qcow2: Image is corrupt; cannot be opened read/write

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this error while trying to run emulator:

> Emulator: -drive
>   if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\Hp.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576: qcow2: Image is corrupt; cannot be opened read/write

Answer (score 0):

Increase the internal storage size of your emulator and run the emulator again.